# Getting attribute list ONLY of particular published layer (WFS or WMS)

Tags: geoserver, wms, wfs

I do NOT want to use GetFeatureInfo as it is implemented using map click. I just want to get the columns list.

I tried

```
http://example.com/geoserver/wfs?
  service=wfs&
  version=2.0.0&
  request=DescribeFeatureType
```

but it did not worked for me.

Comment: please add what the error was, and explain what didn;t work exactly

Comment: You can't get the columns listing from a standard WMS other than through a GetFeatureInfo request.  If a WMS has an associated WFS, there is no guarentee that the WMS layer columns will match the WFS featuretype property names.

Comment: `service=wfs&` is incorrect according to the specification, it should be `service=WFS&`, but it is unlikely that this is the cause of your error.  Otherwise the syntax is correct

Comment: @nmtoken : `service=wfs` (lowercase) is working.

Comment: The WFS specification says the value MUST be `WFS`, so whilst it may work for you it is more correct to use the correct request syntax.

Answer (score 2):

to get WFS featuretypes use this  >

http://example.com/geoserver/wfs?version=1.3.0&request=describeFeatureType&outputFormat=application/json&service=WFS&typeName=layerName

I'm not sure about WMS.

Comment: Version number is incorrect in your URL (there's no WFS version 1.3.0), outputFormat is not required, you don't need to specify a feature type name, (you'll get all types)  and request=DescribeFeatureType not describeFeatureType (value is case sensitive)

Comment: `outputFormat` may not be required but is very useful to change the response to JSON. +1 for that.